# unable to locate ImageView element from android in appium (python)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to find highlighted button in below screenshot of uiautomatorviewer. I am using id of that element, but code gives me NoSuchElementException. I tried using class too but no luck. What's wrong?

uiautomatorviewer screenshot-
[image]

code(please check comment for the exact line which gives error)-

```
import os
from time import sleep

import unittest
import time
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction


# Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p)
)

class SimpleAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '7.0'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'mishra'
        desired_caps['app'] = PATH(
            'Shopronto.apk'
        )

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    #def tearDown(self):
        # end the session
        #self.driver.quit()
    def test_01_correct_username_correct_password(self):
        print "test1"
        Wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        login_tab=Wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "com.shopronto.customer:id/tvLogin")))
        login_tab.click()
        email = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.shopronto.customer:id/etEmail")
        email.send_keys("user1@gmail.com")
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.shopronto.customer:id/etPwd")
        password.send_keys("user123")
        self.driver.back()
        login = self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.shopronto.customer:id/tvBottomBtn")
        login.click() 
        Wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"))).click()
        #below line gives error
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.shopronto.customer:id/ivCategory")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleAndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

When I replace this-

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.shopronto.customer:id/ivCategory")
```

with-

```
        mylist=[]
        self.driver.back()
        mylist = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//android.widget.ImageView")
```

The code keeps running without giving any output (for over 15 mins).

I have also tried this-

```
Wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']"))).click()
```

But no luck.

Comment: I guess , ImageView mean all the icon have same id. You need to use find by elements that return all the value and go by index.

Comment: Yes all the elements have same Id and class. I tried findElements but it returns me an empty list.

Comment: Add code for all elements that you are trying.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you. I have already uploaded code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your all image view's have same ID, So you should use find element by `xpath` with `index` as there is no text with image view.